# contact Form Block explanation

Tags: magento-1.9

```
<!– CONTACT FORM CODE BEGIN–>{{block type='core/template' name='contactForm' template='contacts/form.phtml'}}<!– CONTACT FORM CODE END–>
```

Find above code for call contact Form. can anyone explain me how flow execute  when its called  ?

Like how its find controller and model and action using only above code ?

Sorry for my question if you find its ruff but i am new in magento.

Thanks for any help in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply use this one`{{block type="core/template" template="contacts/form.phtml"}}` without a name, so this mean that your block go to retrieve some template that is located in: `template/contacts/form.phtml` so it will give you a **form** then when you submit the one, it calls the controller and all that follows.

Answer (score 0):

Your above block is not related to controller. It's only related to Block and View(phtml) template.

It's actually parse by

```
// Varien/Filter/Template.php

public function filter($value)
```

When it's parse it's create an instance of type attribute, in your case **type='core/template'** is equivalent of Mage_Core_Block_Template class and corresponding template is **contacts/form.phtml** [app/design/frontend/yourvendor/yourtheme/template/contacts/form.phtml]

For more details check following class:

```
Varien/Filter/Template.php
app/code/core/Mage/Cms/Model/Template/Filter.php
app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Email/Template/Filter.php
```